# How to check duplicate data when import data excel in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

please help, I want import data excel into mysql using codeigniter 3 but when there are some data duplicate will show a message and skip the duplicate data.
this is my controller :

```
 public function import_excel(){
    if(isset($_FILES["fileExcel"]["name"])){
        $path=$_FILES["fileExcel"]["tmp_name"];
        $object=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
        foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
        {         
            $highestRow=$worksheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn=$worksheet->getHighestColumn();
            for($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
            {
                $password=$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$row)->getValue();
                $name=$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                $company=$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$row)->getValue();
                $email=$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $mobile=$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,$row)->getValue();
                $level=$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,$row)->getValue();
                $active=$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7,$row)->getValue();
               
                $temp_data[]=array(
                    'name'=>$name,
                    'company'=>$company,
                    'email'=>strtolower($email),
                    'password'=>password_hash(($password),PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                    'mobile'=>$mobile,
                    'level'=>$level,
                    'active'=>$active
                    );
                
                   
                           
            }
            
                $this->m_data->insert($temp_data);                       
                redirect('userlist');
            }     
         
                    
                              
        }
       
    }
```

this is my model :

```
  public function insert($temp_data){
$this->db->insert_batch('user',$temp_data);

}
```

Thank you very much I hope I find for this solution.

Comment: what do you want to show in your duplicate data message? do you want to show it for each row, or what else?

Comment: Hello sir, I want to display a duplicate value in each row..thank you